# Quarkus Panache Transactional how to close db connections properly

Tags: hibernate, transactions, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have a problem with transactions in Panache Quarkus when dealing with a high count of transactions in parallel

this is my sample code

```java
public Uni<Void> executeLotsOfTransactions() {
    Multi<Integer> multi = Multi.createFrom().range(0, 1000);

    return multi
            .onItem().transformToUniAndMerge(number -> {
                return Uni.createFrom()
                        .deferred(() -> executeSomeTransaction(number))
                        .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())
                        .emitOn(MutinyHelper.executor(Vertx.currentContext()));
            })
            .collect().asList()
            .replaceWithVoid();
}

@Transactional
Uni<Void> executeSomeTransaction(Integer num) {
    Uni<Item> uniItem = someRepo.findSomeData(num); // basically find()
    return uniItem
            .chain(item -> {
                // do some calculation & update with item
                return someRepo.updateItem(item); // basically persist() or update() item
            })
            .onFailure().retry().withBackOff(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).atMost(3);
}
```

note that I use `.deferred()` and `.runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())` so the JTA starts in worker pool

some of the `someRepo.updateItem(item)` is successful, but many of them also fail with this Exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

and this is the repo code:

```java
@Override
public Uni<Void> updateItem(Item item) {
    return Uni.createFrom()
            .voidItem().invoke(() -> updateItemNonUni(item))
            .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())
            .emitOn(MutinyHelper.executor(Vertx.currentContext()));
}

@Transactional(REQUIRED)
void updateItemNonUni(Item item) {
    // this approach is not optimal, should rework
    Item itemFromDB = findById(item.getID());
    itemFromDB.setBalance(item.getBalance());
    itemFromDB.setStatus(item.getStatus());
    itemFromDB.setUpdatedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
    persist(itemFromDB);
}
```

I think at first its because I do the transactions in parallel, so I added retry `.onFailure()`
but this doesn't seem to help because the number of failing operations did not decrease

So I thought it was because the connection from the other `executeSomeTransaction` is not yet closed even if it is done already.

I thought this has something to do with how Uni works, but I'm not 100% sure where I did wrong here.

so my question is, how can I close the db connections properly?

Edit:
I'm using non-reactive **Hibernate-ORM** and Quarkus version **2.16**

Comment: I think you need to limit parallelism with merge as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76520437/175554 for limit value give half of jdbc pool size or 75 percent should be sufficient, writing multi threaded applications takes longer tests, decide the number after you test thoroughly.

Comment: I see, I tried with 50% and it works now but only if I'm using `multi.merge()`. I tried similar thing using `Uni.join().builder()` and it wont work even if I'm limiting its `concurrency`

Comment: Uni and multi works differently [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67495287/uni-combine-all-unis-v-s-multi-onitem-transformtomultiandconcatenate) that may help, and share your findings here :) it is always nice to hear multi threaded solutions and their stories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @ozkanpakdil's comment, I tried to limit the concurrency of my insert and now it works.

this is roughly the solution

```java
public Uni<Void> insertAmounts(List<SomeEntity> itemList) {
    return Multi.createFrom().iterable(ListUtils.partition(itemList, 2000))
            .emitOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())
            .onItem().transformToUni(batchedList -> Uni.createFrom().voidItem()
                    .invoke(() -> InsertManyItemsNonUni(batchedList))
            )
            .merge(50)
            .collect().asList()
            .replaceWithVoid()
            .emitOn(MutinyHelper.executor(Vertx.currentContext()));
}

void InsertManyItemsNonUni(List<SomeEntity> itemList) {
    if (QuarkusTransaction.isActive()) {
        QuarkusTransaction.joiningExisting();
    } else {
        QuarkusTransaction.begin();
    }
    repositoryWriter.persist(itemList);
    QuarkusTransaction.commit();
}
```

note: my max connection pool is 100